# php simple html dom parse img html5 attributes?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

How to use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)  parse `img` html5 attribute: `data-original`

```
$htmls = '<img class="lazy" alt="Nubifragio a Verbania , ferite 2 turiste  Gravi danni, chiesto stato di calamità    foto" title="Nubifragio a Verbania , ferite 2 turiste  Gravi danni, chiesto stato di calamità    foto" data-original="http://www.repubblica.it/images/2012/08/26/130634575-506cc9ae-11b8-4a53-920c-539a3811e46b.jpg" src="http://www.repubblica.it/static/images/homepage/2012/lazy.png" width="130" height="98" style="display: inline; ">';
$html = str_get_html($htmls);
$fata = $html->find('img'); 
foreach($fata as $newimage){
    echo $newimage->data-original; //0
    echo $newimage->src; //http://www.repubblica.it/static/images/homepage/2012/lazy.png
}
```

I could get the attribute `src`, but `data-original` return `0`

Comment: You're saying `$newimage->data - original;`

Comment: @Stephen Sarcsam Kamenar, yes, how to get this value use simple html dom?

Comment: Try `$newimage['data-original'];`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$newimage->data-original;
```

means

```
$newimage->data - original;
```

A way round this is to try:

```
$property = 'data-original';
$newimage->$property;
```

or, to use the alternative syntax:

```
$newimage['data-original'];
```

Comment: right, in php it should be `$newimage->{'data-original'};`, thanks.

Comment: I realize this is old but I came across this, submitted an edit for this to use the proper syntax on the final line.

Comment: perfect solution, really helped me.

Answer (score 7):

Just an FYI:

I tried:

```
$newimage['data-original'];
```

but this is what worked for me:

```
$property = 'data-original';
$newimage->$property;
```

Comment: The alternative syntax didn't work for me neither, but the other one did the trick.

Comment: Same, got an error saying I couldn't use a Simple HTML DOM element as an array. Ended up using `$newImage->{'data-original'}` syntax which worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will work**

$thumbs= $video->find('img[class=image]', 0)->{data-original};

Answer (score 0):

Using **braces** would be more **efficient**:

```
$newimage->{'data-original'};
```

Another Example:

```
<?php
   class foo {
     var $bar = 'I am bar.';
     var $arr = array('I am A.', 'I am B.', 'I am C.');
     var $r   = 'I am r.';
   }

   $foo = new foo();
   $bar = 'bar';
   $baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
   echo $foo->$bar . "\n";
   echo $foo->{$baz[1]} . "\n";

   $start = 'b';
   $end   = 'ar';
   echo $foo->{$start . $end} . "\n";

   $arr = 'arr';
   echo $foo->{$arr[1]} . "\n";

?>
```

Read more about **variables wraped in braces**:
[PHP documentation: Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#language.variables.variable)