# Can't get data-title, just data-slug

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

**HTML**

```
<article class="movie-summary" data-slug="slug-goes-here" data-title="This is a Title">
...
...
</article>
```

**PHP**

```
$html = file_get_html( 'example.com' );
foreach( $html->find('article') as $data) {
    $property = 'data-title';
    echo $data->$property;
}
```

Hey all, so I want to be able to get all data-title from all articles off a particular site. When I use data-slug I get data back yet when I use data-title I get nothing, with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131190/php-simple-html-dom-parse-img-html5-attributes)

Comment: Have you tried this syntax `$data->{'data-titlel'}` ?

Comment: @TahaAzzabi Yes, does nothing :/

Comment: This `echo $data->$property;` should actually work too. Show more html you are parsing and intended result. Maybe not every `<article>` tag has `data-title` attribute

Comment: https://bhr.voxcinemas.com/movies/comingsoon That's the website I'm looking at @Alexey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the actual HTML code you are trying to parse (the link provided at comments), you see that it is not valid:

```
<article  class="movie-summary hero" data-slug="aiyaary-hindi"data-title="Aiyaary">
...
</article>
```

Meaning, there is no space between `data-slug` and `data-title` attributes. So to fix this I suggest to add necessary spaces. Like so:

```
function placeNeccessarySpaces($contents) {
    return preg_replace('/"data-title/', '" data-title', $contents);
}
```

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17216101/4471134). Then:

```
$contents = placeNeccessarySpaces(file_get_contents('http://example.com'));
$html = str_get_html($contents);
foreach( $html->find('article') as $data) {
    $property = 'data-title';
    echo $data->$property;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! I was using "inspect" to view the source code, which Chrome has corrected the HTML! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply working fine, Verified result

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html('<article class="movie-summary" data-slug="slug-goes-here" data-title="This is a Title"></article>');

    foreach( $html->find('article') as $data) {
        $property = 'data-title';
        echo $data->$property;
    }

?>
```

got the file 'simple_html_dom.php' from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

output:

[image]